# Covariance in generic collections C#

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a some classes and interface

```
public interface IGeoObject
    {
        GeoCoordinate GetGeocoordinate();
    }

public class User : IGeoObject
    {
        public GeoCoordinate GetGeocoordinate()
        {
            //...
            return GeoCoordinate;           
        }
    }  

public class Venue : IGeoObject
    {    
        public GeoCoordinate GetGeocoordinate()
        {
            //...
            return GeoCoordinate;
        }
    }

public class Place : IGeoObject
    {    
        public GeoCoordinate GetGeocoordinate()
        {
            //...
            return GeoCoordinate;
        }
    }
```

I have, example variable users with type `List<User>`

And I have method with signature

```
double GetMinDistance(List<IGeoObject> objects, GeoCoordinate position)
```

I can't pass users to `GetMinDistance`, because covariance of generic types not work.

I can create additional list and use method `.ConvertAll` (or `.CasT<T>`):

```
List<IGeoObject> list = new List<User>(listUser).ConvertAll(x => (IGeoObject)x);
var dist = GeoTest.GetMinDistance(list, position);
```

I'm not sure that this is the most elegant solution. Most embarrassing that the **caller must do this conversion**.

This is similar to my problems in the architecture? There are more elegant solutions?

P.S. Long story, but I really can not give the coordinates of the same species in all classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) is not covariant.

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, 
    IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable
```

As you can see, there is no `out` keyword in class declaration.

You have to use [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) instead to get covariance support.

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
```

That's because `List<T>` has a set of methods that allows you modifying the collection, and with covariance you would lose compile type safety of these operations. `IEnumerable<T>` only allows you to iterate over the collection and that's why it can be marked as covariant.

Comment: In other worse, if he changed the method signature to `double GetMinDistance(IEnumerable<IGeoObject> objects, GeoCoordinate position)` then he could pass `List<User>`.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the signature to:

```
double GetMinDistance<TGeoObject>(List<TGeoObject> objects, GeoCoordinate position)
    where TGeoObject : IGeoObject 
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a explicit (cast) or an implicit operator that take an `List<User>` and convert it to a `List<IGeoObject>`.

```
public static explicit operator List<IGeoObject>(List<IGeoObject> ls)
{
  return new ls.ConvertAll(x => (IGeoObject)x);
}
```